# Which Firefox extension checks html markup when you view source?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I used to have a great Firefox add-on for this and I can't remember the name of it..

when you looked at the source it would sit at the bottom (like firebug) and check your HTML markup and suggest things like "doctype given is html4.0, looks like xhtml strict" etc

I thought it was the web developer toolbar but that doesn't seem to add anything to the bottom of the source pane?

Comment: Should be a SuperUser.com question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are looking for HTML Validator : https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/249

Comment: Does it check HTML 5 Validation too?

Answer (score 1):

It might be the [HTML Validator](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/249).

Answer (score 0):

this addon http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/ in the "tools" menu has an option where you can VALIDATE HTML

Comment: you install this add-on and press Ctr+Shift+H

Comment: i have a feeling the validator in the toolbar wont work on a local host though, thanks for the tip none the less

Answer (score -1):

It's Web Developer Toolbar: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60

Comment: i have the Web Developer 1.1.8 extension is that the one?
how do i enable the mark up thingy?!
cheers!

Comment: Hmmz i don't know if this is what you're looking for, you could check under information and view document outline.